# Run a "always on" redis keyspace event listener with django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, redis, python-multithreading

I have deployed a django application on an EC2 instance. I have used NGINX as the reverse proxy and gunicorn as the WSGI server to serve requests from the django app.

As part of a functionality within the app, I want to listen to redis keyspace notifications on expiry of certain keys (which match a given pattern) and upon receiving the expiry event, perform something (write something to the database). This would require a piece of code (redis-listener) to be constantly running alongside my django app to listen to any incoming redis event.

I am not able to arrive at an optimal implementation for this listener. One approach is that I can use threading to run the listener in a separate thread than the main django app thread (by running the listener in a new thread inside the ready() method) but then for each incoming request, gunicorn will create or assign a new worker process with its own instance of the django app and the listener thread. So, I end up running as many redis listener threads as there are active incoming requests. And each redis event will be effectively listened multiple times simultaneously, which is not what I want.

Is there an alternative and more efficient way to do this?

I figure the optimal solution will somehow involve running this listener outside of the main django thread served by gunicorn (?)

Comment: If you can use kafka then it will be good for your use case .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DeepakTripathi could you please explain more about how can I use Kafka? I am still a learner